# Inno Setup UninstallIcon Disappears

Tags: icons, inno-setup, missing-data, uninstallation

I am doing something wrong with the UninstallerIcon I use this piece of Code:

```
UninstallDisplayIcon=....(Iconlocation)
```

and then when I unplug the Disk with the Icon the icon disappears:

[image]

[image]

I hope you can help me out :)

Best Regards,

Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`UninstallDisplayIcon`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstalldisplayicon) must point to a permanent file on the destination machine. Not to the source drive of the installer. That typically means that you have to *install* the icon and point the `UninstallDisplayIcon` to the installed copy:

```
[Setup]
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\uninstall.ico

[Files]
Source: uninstall.ico; DestDir: {app}
```

---

Note that the `UninstallDisplayIcon` is loaded by Windows on the destination machine, not Inno Setup itself. Windows supports other formats, like `.exe` and `.dll`, in addition to `.ico`.